# The meaning of anxious when followed by subjunctive

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, subjunctives

As far as I know, anxious can mean both nervous and eager, although I've heard that the second meaning is not that acceptable.
When anxious is followed by subjunctive, can it have both meanings?
For instance, are the following sentences both correct?

> I'm anxious that you meet my friends.
>   I'm anxious that he hurt himself.

Comment: Imho, the first one would be better as *I'm anxious **for you to** meet my friends*, and second would be better with a different verb - *I'm **worried/concerned** that he [might have] hurt himself.*

Comment: You heard wrong. *Anxious and eager both mean ‘looking forward to something,’ but they have different connotations. Eager suggests enthusiasm about something, a positive outlook: I’m eager to get started on my vacation. Anxious implies worry about something: I’m anxious to get started before it rains.* [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anxious).

Comment: If you want the subjunctive in the second clause, *I'm anxious lest he hurt himself* works. See *lest* definition 1.1 in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lest), and the accompanying usage note regarding the subjunctive after *lest*.

Comment: @GoDucks How can 'anxious' mean 'looking forward to something' and have negative connotations?

Comment: @V.Lydia In the sense that the event has not yet occurred.

Comment: doesn't "looking forward to" mean that sb is excited and can't wait for something to happen?

Comment: @V.Lydia It doesn't mean that you are looking forward to something at all. That's not oaccurate. It means that you want something to happen, but until it actually happens you feel nervous about it in case it *doesn't* happen. So being anxious to do something conveys that you want to do it, but you're a bit worried, not that you feel happy thinking about it.

Comment: I'm anxious that he might hurt  himself.

Comment: Re *I've heard that the second meaning (**anxious** = **eager, keen**) is not that acceptable.* I think in practice that meaning only arises because the "literal" anxiety in something like *He's anxious to leave* refers the fact that he is and will continue to be anxious *unless and until he leaves* The sense of "keenness" implicitly refers to his desperately wanting to *resolve his current state of anxiety* by leaving. But both "senses" have been associated with the word ever since it came into  English some 4-5 centuries ago.

Comment: How come then a dictionary says that "anxious" means  or can mean "earnestly desirous; eager"?

Answer (score 2):

To be *anxious* means to have anxiety/discomfort.

The subjunctive is followed by certain verbs and *to desire* is one of them.  So when a subjunctive follows *anxious* it follows a similar pattern and the meaning is "desire strongly to the point of causing one anxiety, discomfort."

Of course the anxiety/discomfort may not actually exist and the expression is used for exaggeration or emphasis.

So it does in a sense combine the meanings of both *anxious* and *desire* when used like this.

> I'm anxious that you meet my friends.

This sounds fine and the speaker/writer is saying he/she wants you to meet his/her friends very very much.

But, you can also say something like this:

> I'm anxious that they will not make it here in time.

This means the possibility of "they will not make it here in time" is making you anxious.

So:

> I'm anxious that he hurt himself.

It's unlikely that a reasonable person would be anxious to hurt someone, so probably most people would assume that *hurt* here is past tense and that you are saying that the possibility of him having hurt himself is making you anxious.

Say:

> I'm anxious for him to hurt himself.

if you want to express without ambiguity that you just really wish someone would hurt themselves.

Comment: *I'm anxious that you meet my friends* could be interpreted as *You meet my friends, and it worries me.* So I don't agree it "sounds fine".

Comment: No, that meaning would be conveyed by "You meeting my friends makes me anxious."

Comment: "No"?! *Anxious* usually signals a negative, so *I'm anxious that you meet my friends* does not unproblematically convey *I'm eager for you to meet my friends*. The formulation would, in fact, cause me to (1) assume that the meetings were happening and (2) wonder what was so anxiety-provoking about them. Also, in your alternative, I would say *Your meeting* rather than *you meeting*, but then I'm pedantic that way.

Comment: It can also mean to want very much.  Google's definition says this too.

Answer (score -2):

I would not write this: **I'm anxious that you meet my friends**.

You could write: I am eagerly looking forward to you meeting my friends. Its a "positive anticipation".

This is fine: **I'm anxious that he hurt himself**.

Anxious (and anxiousness) implies 'worry' and 'concern.

Comment: No, we would say *I'm anxious that he not hurt himself* or *I'm anxious lest he hurt himself*.

Comment: Actually, if you start to Google *anxious that* the first auto-complete suggestion is *anxious that I might be pregnant*; if you actually run that search, the top associated hits are for women who *do not* want to be pregnant, rather than those who are desperately hoping that they *are*. So *I'm anxious that I'm pregnant* = *I'm worried that I might be pregnant* and *I'm anxious that he hurt himself* would, in fact, mean *I'm worried that he might be hurt*.